# Checkin project to a different SVN repository location

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have one project that I checked out from one SVN repository location and done some changes in that project in various java files and now I want to check out this project in to some different SVN repository. How can I do this. As when I am right clicking on that project I am not getting `share this project`. I am working with eclipse. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: Have you already disconnected the Eclipse project from the original online SVN repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a termnial fire it up.

```
svn copy http://xyz/base_project/branches/current_branch http://xyz/base_project/branches/target_branch
```

Then do a svn switch to that branch you just created.

```
svn switch http://xyz/base_project/branches/target_branch .
```

Finally commit the entire stuff now.

```
svn commit .
```

Comment: Can we do this within the eclipse not from the terminal. Can i do this way..  [link](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/scm/svn/disconnect-and-reconnect-svn-project-to-another-location-subclipse-version)

Comment: wat operating system are you using ?

Comment: i am not sure how to do it in eclipse, but if you are not confortable using command line, you can use TortoiseSVN, which is a really good client for windows http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/